# intermediate value is not iterable

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, infura, ethereumjs-tx

I try to construct a transaction with Node (11.4.0), ethereumjs-tx (1.3.7)  and web3 (1.0.0-beta.55) and Infura.
Infura gives me '0x35b' for the nonce,
then I create the tx:

```
amount = 0.001;
nonce = '0x35b';
txParams = {
    to: "0x130f6562d441D25A812865527761EE7246AF0297", //receiver,
    value: web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'ether') ),
    gas: 21000,
    gasPrice: 20 * 1000000000, // converts the gwei price to wei
    nonce: nonce,
    chainId: 3  // Ropsten
}
```

Then I create the tx:

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
let tx = new EthereumTx(txParams);
```

The tx seems to be invalid:

```
console.log(tx.validate())
```

prints 'false', and if I try to send the tx to Infura (method: eth_sendRawTransaction) I get:

```
(intermediate value) is not iterable
```

Any idea what my problem is ?

Comment: How do you sign the transaction?

Comment: I have a feeling `console.log(tx)` might help you a lot here.